# Proving an inclusion related to algebraic sets and interpreting it

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, radicals

I want to prove that

> $I(X_1 \cap X_2) = \sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}$

for algebraic sets $X_1=Z(G_1)$ and $X_2=Z(G_2)$, with $G_1,G_2 \subseteq \mathbb{K}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$.

Remark: Unfortunately I named the indeterminates $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ but obviously the first ones $X_1,X_2$ are algebraic sets and not indeterminates.

I've already proved $\supseteq$ but I'm struggling with proving $\subseteq$.

The problem is equivalent to prove that, if $g \in I(X_1 \cap X_2)$, then $g^n \in I(X_1)+I(X_2)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but the $+$ is bothering me... some hint can definitely put myself in the right way.

Also, I'd like to:

> Interpret geometrically what it means to have $I(X_1 \cap X_2) \neq I(X_1)+I(X_2)$,

thing that I don't see at all.

Comment: Re: your remark. There is an edit function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both $I(X_1\cap X_2)$ and $\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}$ are radical ideals, by the Nullstellensatz it is enough to prove that $Z(I(X_1\cap X_2))=Z(\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)})$. We have $Z(I(X_1\cap X_2))=X_1\cap X_2$ and $Z(\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)})=Z(I(X_1)+I(X_2))=Z(I(X_1))\cap Z(I(X_2))=X_1\cap X_2$.

The inequality $I(X_1\cap X_2)\neq I(X_1)+ I(X_2)$ is because an algebraic reason: the sum of two radical ideals is not in general a radical ideal.

**Edit**: In the proof I assumed that the field is algebraically closed. The equality does not hold without this hypothesis. For example, take $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, $X_1:\ x^2+y^2=1$, and $X_2:\ x=2$. Then $X_1\cap X_2=\emptyset$, so that $I(X_1\cap X_2)=\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, whereas the ideal $I(X_1)+I(X_2)=(x^2+y^2-1)+(x-2)$ (and hence also its radical) is a proper ideal.

Comment: In the first part I'll try to understand the 2nd equalty from the end.

Comment: In the second part I think you have made some mistake with the cap but I understand what you said. However, I'd like to have a geometrical interpretation of ''the sum od two radical ideals is not in general a radical ideal''

Comment: However, I found an answer to the second part in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110903/geometrical-interpretation-of-ix-1-cap-x-2-neq-ix-1ix-2-x-i-algebrai so let's focus only on the first part

Comment: If $z$ is annihilated by all $I(X_1)+I(X_2)$ then in particular it is annihilated by each $I(X_1)$ and $I(X_2)$. Reciprocally, if $z$ is annihilated by $I(X_1)$ and $I(X_2)$ then it is annihilated all $I(X_1)+I(X_2)$ because the set of polynomials which annihilate $z$ is an ideal.

Comment: @Diego: Why is it enough to show that the zero-sets of the ideals are equal ?

Comment: @tj_ Because of Nullstellensatz, and we can eliminate the square root because they are radical ideals

Comment: Yes, but the Nullstellensatz requires an algebraically closed field which isn't assumed in the question. When making additional assumptions in an answer it's good practise, to point them out explicitly and not to introduce them implicitly.

Comment: @Diego Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand why $Z(\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)})=Z(I(X_1)+I(X_2))$, maybe it is obvious and I am missing something

Comment: The inclusion $\subseteq$ is clear, but the other one isn't clear for me

Comment: Let $z\in Z(I)$ and $f\in\sqrt{I}$. For some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f^n\in I$. Then $(f(z))^n=f^n(z)=0$ and therefore $f(z)=0$.

Comment: @Diego Are you assuming $K$ to be algebraically closed ? It seems you are using $1-1$ correspondence between algebraic sets and radical ideals.

Comment: @user371231. Yes. I edited my answer to clarify this point.