# For $Y_1,Y_2$ closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$, $\mathcal{I}(Y_1 \cap Y_2)= \text{rad}(\mathcal{I}(Y_1)+\mathcal{I}(Y_2))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $Y_1,Y_2$ are two (Zariski) closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$, for any field $k$. Then how do I show that $\mathcal{I}(Y_1 \cap Y_2)= \text{rad}(\mathcal{I}(Y_1)+\mathcal{I}(Y_2))$.

Clearly $\text{rad}(\mathcal{I}(Y_1)+\mathcal{I}(Y_2)) \subseteq \mathcal{I}(Y_1 \cap Y_2)$. How can I prove the converse ? I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving an inclusion related to algebraic sets and interpreting it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178972/proving-an-inclusion-related-to-algebraic-sets-and-interpreting-it)

Comment: Is this not true if $k$ is not algebraically closed ? The solution of above link is under the assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed.